# Compiling fish shell under Cygwin?

Tags: shell, cygwin, autotools, fish

Has anyone been able to correctly compile fish under Cygwin? I found [this post](http://dave-programming.blogspot.com/2008/02/fish-shell-compiled-on-cygwin.html) about modifying configure.ac but I'm getting all sorts of errors. The usual configure, make, make install isn't working for me, maybe I'm doing something wrong here...
Can someone please walk me through how to get it to compile?

Comment: Are you using fish shell under Cygwin? Was you able to compile it correctly after seeing the answer here? Could you provide detailed instructions, or perhaps a prepackaged binary?

Comment: @muriloq: I see you already got the [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/328340/how-to-use-fish-shell-in-cygwin/328388#328388). I should say that even though I got it to compile correctly, it was running a bit slow for my taste, plus all key bindings were not functioning correctly.. I eventually gave up on Fish as my main shell in Cygwin

Comment: Thanks Amro, but I'm still having problems (see my comment at superuser)... And since you said the key bindings don't work I'll probably give up, too.

Comment: @muriloq: please don't disregard it on my account, I could be doing something wrong too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After modifying `configure.ac` you may need to rerun `autoconf` to create a new `configure` script. Without doing this, you're still running the original `configure` script that comes with the source download, so changes you made to `configure.ac` will have no effect.